# Что означает этот код.

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста что означает этот код:

```
choice=(char) System.in.read();
```

И зачем используется (char)?

Answer (score 3):

Из [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29):

> ```
> public abstract int read()
>                   throws IOException
> ```
>
> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an `int` in the range `0` to `255`. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value `-1` is returned.

Итак, `read` пытается считать байт из потока, и возвращает либо значение этого байта от `0` до `255` (если байт реально прочитан), либо `-1` в конце потока. Если для приведённого кода в силу каких-либо условий гарантировано, что конец потока ещё не достигнут, код верен: считывается значение от `0` до `255` и приводится к типу считанного символа. Если же конец потока реально может встретиться, в коде баг: игнорируется возможный конец потока, он будет распознан как символ с кодом `255`.

Конец потока `System.in` может быть достигнут если, например, пользователь нажмёт `Ctrl-D` в стандартных Linux-shell'ах или (при некоторых условиях) `Ctrl-Z` в Windows console-окне. Или если используется перенаправление потока ввода.

Answer (score 2):

System.in.read() возвращает код введенного символа, т.е. int. char нужен, чтобы получить сам символ.